# Illustrator CC - Can't set angle of a line segment to include a decimal?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, isometric

So I'm trying to set the angle of a line to 26,56 degrees in order to create an isometric grid, however when I do this within the line tool, it defaults to a horizonal 360 degrees instead.

I thought this could have been to do with the line snapping to the grid (although I'm making this with points not pixels) and I've turned off the alignment of objects, but the issue still persists. My version of Illustrator doesn't include the option to uncheck this box either when creating a new document, and while I've found a work around I'm doubting whether that's even the problem now!

Any ideas would be most welcome, I've used Photoshop and InDesign a tonne, but Illustrator I'm not as familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the path and set the angle from the **Transform Panel**:

[image: Transform Panel]